# Process cloned input fields

Tags: php

I have cloned input fields in my project, now I just have to get the information out somehow from those fields.
Is there a way to get the values using php?
Many thanks for the help!

```
<html>
<body>
<head><title>Dividing</title></head>
<h1>Enter questions, and possible answers</h1>

<div id="quest">
<input type="text" name="question"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="answer"><br><br>
<button onclick="Clones()">add new question</button><br><br>
</div>


<script>
var counter=1;
function Clones(){
var element= document.getElementById("quest");
var clone=element.cloneNode(true);
clone.id=counter;
document.body.appendChild(clone);
counter++;
}
</script>
<button>End input</button><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot get the values using PHP, but you can post the form to a PHP script.

Comment: Can you please explain? The main problem is, that the input fields are in a div, not a form.

Comment: Is there a way to reference them like: quest.question? That would solve half the problem.

Comment: If you want to send the values to PHP, use an ajax call.